# Laravel Login attempt always return false

Tags: laravel, authentication

This is fresh laravel 9 Project, I didn't touch anything about auth but it is not working.

```
Route::get('test',function (){
$user = \App\Models\User::create([
    'name' => fake()->name(),
    'email' => 'a@d.com',
    'email_verified_at' => now(),
    'password' => bcrypt('password'), // password
]);
dd($user);
});
```

When i hit /test route, I got new user record.

But when i hit /test2, it returns false

```
Route::get('test2',function (){
$user = auth()->attempt([
    'email' => 'a@d.com',
    'password' => 'password'
]);

dd($user);
```

});

And my config/auth.php is same as default laravel 9 config/auth.php

Any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel encrypts your `password` by default, so you don't need to encrypt it anymore.

Use this:

```
$user = \App\Models\User::create([
    'name' => fake()->name(),
    'email' => 'a@d.com',
    'email_verified_at' => now(),
    'password' => 'password', // password
]);
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Why none told me that before :D

Comment: Can get by experience :) Good luck!

Comment: Yes, but it used to be required to save password with bcrypt method. Anyway thanks again :))

Comment: Unless you change User model.

Comment: depends which scaffolding you use